# Coveo Config based on Environment

Tags: configuration, indexing, coveo

I am new to coveo and our dev environment is not working as expected, I am trying to duplicate the QA Environment and set up dev environment

When i do this what are all the changes i should keep in mind ,so that when i rebuild index it doesn't affect QA but indexes only Dev DBs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to review the coveo search config files and make copies of QA index definitions and name them with "DEV_" prefix so you know. Once you define for all databases (master, web, core) you should see these new index definitions in the index manager in sitecore control panel. Select only these indexes (prefix "DEV_") and index them.